# SciKit Learn Parallel Processing 0.17 to 0.18 (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

For some reason the code below is useing all available cores even though I have set n_jobs equal to 1. Have I missed something or should I submit an issue at scikit ?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

liReg = linear_model.LinearRegression(n_jobs=1)

a = np.random.rand(10000,20)
b = np.random.rand(10000)

for i in range(1000):
    liReg.fit(a, b)
    liReg.predict(a)
```

I have two identical servers but one runs scikit v0.18 and one v0.17 - this only happens when using 0.18.

Here is the output of `time python example.py`:

Using 0.17 - just uses one core:

```
real    0m8.381s
user    0m6.387s
sys     0m1.677s
```

Using 0.18 - uses all cores:

```
real    0m32.308s # I guess longer due to overhead of parallel process management
user    2m53.612s
sys     20m48.285s
```

Comment: it's weird to have that much overhead with parallel processing. I tried on my computer, it uses all cores but runs in 6 seconds (using %timeit in Ipython). I have sklearn v0.18

Comment: Using `n_jobs`=2, it still appears to use all my cores BUT is slower (10 seconds with %timeit)

Comment: (I have 64 dual-core cpus... so that might explain the more dramatic effect...) Still weird anyway that its using all cores anyway no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @GaelVaroquaux on Github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8883#issuecomment-301567818

> Most likely you are using a parallel-enabled linear algebra library
>   (like MKL or openBLAS). Hence, it is not scikit-learn that is doing
>   parallel computing, and it cannot control it (it is a component that
>   is used inside scikit-learn). You need to find out how to control the
>   corresponding computing brick.

In my case I was using OpenBLAS on fedora linux so I simply added:
`export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` to my `.bashrc` to disable multithreading within the linear algebra call.